# Why isn't this twitter api ajax request working in IE7?

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter, internet-explorer-7, cross-domain

This code works; only, not with IE7.  I read that I could get it to work in IE7 if I include `callback=?` to force JSONP, but it still isn't working.

Any tips, suggestions, noticeable errors?

```
<div id="twitter">
</div>
<script>
$(function(){
   $.ajaxSetup({ 
      cache: true,
      crossDomain: true,
   });
   $.getJSON('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?callback=?&screen_name=bozdoz', function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(i, tweet) {
      $('#twitter').append('<li>'+tweet.text+'</li>');
      });
   });
});
</script>
```

--

### UPDATE

This is the code I should have been using.  This was compiled after scouring StackOverflow for hours. Works great in IE7.  Thanks everyone.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=bozdoz',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  cache: false,
  crossDomain: true,
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function(data){
 $.each(data, function(i){
 $('#twitter').append('<p>'+this.text+'</p>');
 if(i==2) return false;
 });
},
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
 $('#twitter').append('<p>'+jqXHR+" "+textStatus+" "+errorThrown+'</p>');
}
 });
```

Comment: I wish IE7 would die just like IE6 did.  IE8 runs on XP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try setting the `contentType`

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  cache: true,
  crossDomain: true,
  scriptCharset: "utf-8" ,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
 });
```

P.S the json returned by the api is not validated as valid json by [`jsonlint`](http://www.jsonlint.com)

also always append the `&callback=?` to the end of the URL

Comment: So good.  Worked beautifully in IE7.  Thanks.  I knew someone would know the answer. :)  Is the scriptCharset necessary do you think?

Comment: As it turns out, this solution seems to work only half the time.  When I refresh the page, it seems to have a 50/50 chance of working.  Any idea why?

Comment: Nope.  Not working.  I'm on a contractor-designed sharepoint site, working for an organization which runs on IE7.  It's a nuisance.

Comment: one more thing that i can think of is may be you are initiating the second ajax call before the first is completed try setting `async:false` which by the way is highly not recommended

Comment: When I set an error callback, it returns "undefined" a bunch of times.

Comment: is this 50/50 behavior only in IE7? because the api may be limiting the the ajax calls

Comment: Looks like it's working now.  I'll update my question with the new code I'm using.  Thanks for your ongoing help. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra , in your code.

You want...

```
$.ajaxSetup({ 
  cache: true,
  crossDomain: true
});
```

Comment: I noticed that too; pretty sure it's insignificant though.  Just tested it, same results.

Comment: it doesnt matter in the latest browsers but it does on IE.. please take care of it

Comment: IE hates trailing commas in objects, it *will* crash IE if you don't remove it.

Comment: I'm tempted to add it again, just to see if you're right.  I had the extra comma in there for awhile, with nothing going wrong.  Only, nothing was going right.  Thanks for the response!  I had to set contentType apparently.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div id="twitter">
</div>
<script>
$(function(){
   $.ajaxSetup({ 
      cache: true,
      crossDomain: true
   });
   $.getJSON('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=bozdoz&callback=?', function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(i) {
      $('#twitter').append('<li>'+this.text+'</li>');
      });
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery abstracts javascript. It shouldn't matter what browser it's run on.

Comment: When it comes to IE, every little thing matters.  It's terrible.  Thanks for your response! :)

Answer (score 1):

here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/8h2Sv/3

showed you differnt ways to achieve it..